# RHEL server unexpectedly became inaccessible via any means (ssh, https)

Tags: ssh, apache-2.4, redhat

The machine runs a LAMP stack (httpd, mariadb and php), and both web server and ssh are running but not accessible from remote systems.  The issue began randomly an hour ago and the system immediately became unresponsive (both over my existing ssh connection and via httpd).

System is currently up and accessible via idrac, and I am able to log in and issue commands over idrac in terminal.

`firewalld` is active and shows ports for http, https and ssh are enabled (among others). Stopping `firewalld` service doesn't resolve the issue.

[image]

`nmap` shows varying results (commands issued from the server).

```
nmap localhost -p 22
Host is up
22/tcp open ssh
```

if I specify the server's IP or FQDN with `nmap`:

```
nmap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 22
Note: Host seems down
```

[image]

The same `nmap` check from a remote system shows host is up:

```
acoder@lappy ~ $ nmap my.domain.name -p 22
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-12-10 08:52 EST
Nmap scan report for my.domain.name (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.014s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.29 seconds
```

`sshd` is up and running

[image]

If I had local keys set up, I could probably log on to ssh via localhost with

```
ssh localhost
```

It gives permission denied (due to my not having keys set up)

If I issue the same but specify the server's actual IP:

```
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

`ssh` returns `Connection timed out`

[image]

When issuing `ssh my.domain.name` from a remote system, I get `Connection refused`:

```
acoder@lappy ~ $ ssh -vvv my.domain.name
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "my.domain.name" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to my.domain.name [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host my.domain.name port 22: Connection refused
```

From the server, `telnet` refuses connection on port 22:

```
[acoder@my.domain.name]# telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connect3ed to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH7.4 
Connection refused by foreign host.
[acoder@my.domain.name]#
```

I'm able to ssh FROM this server into other servers. Just not into it.

I show active link light on the network device:

```
ethtool em1
```

[image]

Conversely, if `nmap` shows port 443 as available when checking from a remote system:

```
acoder@lappy ~ $ nmap my.domain.name -p 443
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-12-09 23:59 EST
Nmap scan report for my.domain.name (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.013s latency).

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.41 seconds
```

Accessing the same domain in a browser yields "Unable to connect"

`tcpdump -D`:

[image]

Here is output of `tcpdump -i em1 port 22`:

[image]

I'm able to ping our DNS server from this server. The server is able to mount shared drives on other servers.

What else am I missing here?

Comment: can you check your ip address by issue " ip addr " command. by the information you gave, i think your ip address has been changed.  if your server has a private ip address and you publish your services via NAT or PAT please check things with your service provider ...

Comment: 'Connection refused' on localhost after showing SSH banner looks weird. Do you have fail2ban? Do you have any connection restrictions in sshd config (like MaxStartups etc)? What is in ssh logs (/var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log)?

Comment: @Salar ip is unchanged. I've tried using the direct IP with all of my commands above, same results.

Comment: @AlexD, fail2ban is not installed. No special sshd restrictions (MaxStartups specifically is commented out). I'm not seeing anything in tail secure or 'journalctl -xe' immediately after a 'connection refused' attempt. sshd_config LogLevel is presently set to VERBOSE.

Comment: You said that stopping `firewalld` doesn't resolve the problem; does that actually clear the firewall? After stopping `firewalld`, are there still rules defined if you run `iptables-save`? If you run `tcpdump` on the server while trying to connect from a remote host, do you see the traffic show up on the server?

Comment: @larsks, stopping `firewalld` service clears the firewall. When `firewalld` is running, I see rules printed with `iptables-save`. After stopping `firewalld`, nothing is returned from `iptables-save`. Working on tcpdump now one sec.

Comment: @larsks `tcpdump -i em1 tcp port 22` shows no output while simultaneously attempting to connect via ssh/port 22 from a remote system.

Comment: That really suggests the problem is somewhere other than the local system.

Comment: Confirmed, there was an unexpected DNS change. thanks for your help.